# Ajax In Mozilla Panel

Tags: html, ajax, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

i try to use Mozilla add on for create log in form . i need to use ajax to find out if username and password is correct or not .

i read about [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) Method in add on but i only need to get info in panel.html page . i usually use XML HTTP REQUEST in chrome extension but it's not worked in Mozilla .
i already try this

```
var latestTweetRequest = Request({url: "http://somthing/login.phpusername="+username+"&password="+password,onComplete: function (response) {alert(response); }});
```

is it possible at all???

Comment: Its very possible and very simple, it looks like you are using the firefox sdk is that right? Methods vary based on approach thats why i ask

Comment: Yeah i use `firefox sdk` .;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a login.js file to the html form (must be external), get the info from the form as usual and make a XMLHTTPRequest in that file instead of doing it in the addon main.js